# Stop execution of button click when some other button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

consider the below two button click events , i want the output cancel_click event to stop the process of hellotest_click event and redirect

```
  protected async void hellotest_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        await Task.Run(() => hello1());
        await Task.Run(() => hello2());          
    }

      //if i click another button , say 

    protected async void cancel_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/trial/main.aspx", false);
        Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();         
    }

//  i want the output cancel_click event to stop the process of hellotest_click event and redirect.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly I don't think this is possible in general case. Imagine your project gets as big as the SO and you use a farm of many servers to handle users. Different clicks might easily arrive to different servers.

Any solution I can imagine is either not that simple or doesn't work correctly for example if the user has several tabs.

Probably the best thing you can do is

- introduce some service for background execution
- introduce some registry of tasks being executed
- return ID of the newly created task immediately to the browser and
  show some progress UI
- regularly at some interval ask server about completion of the task
- when user clicks cancel, pass the ID of the task to the server and
  ask your service to stop executing that task by ID.